# native script facebook//google sso serverside

Tags: facebook, nativescript, google-sso

Starting to plan out a new app. One API to deliver mobile and web apps.

When mobile apps are not in the requirements I typical opt for server-side flow for facebook and google, ie send the user off the fb of goo and they then return back to a defined url. Less code to write that way and IMO easier to maintain.

However, as we are building for mobile this time, is this possible? We aim to be using native script + vuejs... but I get the feeling server-side flow might not be possible... any experienced advise here would be much appreciated.

Comment: I guess you are looking for [nativescript-social-login](https://github.com/mkloubert/nativescript-social-login) which allows you to perform SSO. There is also an option to use [nativescript-oauth2](https://github.com/alexziskind1/nativescript-oauth2).

Comment: do you know if is possible to use the javascript sdk within a native script app:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web

Comment: That was designed to work within browser environment, so I don't think so. With native apps, you must use the native sdk which is implemented in the social login plugin.